# Symfony2 Doctrine2 query with array parameter

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to make query like this:

```
SELECT p.pid, p.url FROM products as p WHERE url_crc IN (FNV_64("http://url1.com/"),FNV_64("http://url2.com/"))
```

I need to use FNV_64 hash function for every array variable. **I CAN'T make hashes before passing variables to query builder. This hash functions is only avaliable as MySQL extension.**

How can i make this using Symfony2 ? 
For example, using:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('p.pid')
            ->from('SRC\MainBundle\Entity\Product', 'p')
            ->where('p.url_crc IN (FNV_64(:urls))') // error HERE
            ->setParameter('urls', $hashes_array)
            ->getQuery();
```

Wouldn't work. The only way i can this of is:

```
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT p.pid, p.url FROM products as p
                                WHERE url_crc IN (' . join(',', $tmp_array) . ')', $rsm);
```

Where tmp_array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FNV_64("http://url1.com/")
    [1] => FNV_64("http://url2.com/")
)
```

Is there better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always bypass DQL.  However, Doctrine2 was designed to support various database engines, and allows you to add "vendor specific SQL functionalities in DQL".  You can read [This link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) to see how you could code in support for your mysql extension.  There's also a link to a github repo with a number of extensions you can look at for examples.

One other thing-- I found at least one php implementation of the FNV hash [here.](http://code.google.com/p/boyanov/source/browse/?repo=prototypes#hg/fnvhash)